# Black line at bottom of WebCamTexture image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

When getting video input from a webcam via WebCamTexture the bottom row of the returned image is completely black (RGB = 0,0,0).
I have tried several different webcams and get the same result with all of them.
I do get a correct image when using the Windows 10 Camera app and also when getting a webcam feed in Processing or Java.

The black line (always 1 pixel high and as wide as the image) appears when showing video on the canvas, saving a snapshot to disk and also when looking directly at the pixel data with GetPixels32().

Here is the black-line at the Bottom of the picture image:

[image]

I have confirmed that the image returned is the correct size, i.e. the black row is not an extra row. It's always the lowest line of the image that is black.

I have included the c# code I'm using below.

What is the cause of this black line and is there a way to avoid it?

I have looked for any information on this issue but not found anything online. I'm a complete beginner at Unity and would be grateful for any help.

I'm using Unity version 5.6.2 but had the same issue with 5.5

```
public class CamController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
    private WebCamDevice[] devices;

    void Start()
    {
        //start webcam
        webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        webcamTexture.deviceName = devices[0].name;
        webcamTexture.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //if user presses C capture cam image
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            captureImage();
    }

    void captureImage()
    {
        //get webcam pixels
        Color32[] camPixels;
        camPixels = webcamTexture.GetPixels32();

        //print pixel data for first and second (from bottom) lines of image to console
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Line: " + y);
            for (int x = 0; x < webcamTexture.width; x++)
            {
                Debug.Log(x + " - " + camPixels[y * webcamTexture.width + x]);
            }
        }

        //save webcam image as png
        Texture2D brightBGTexture = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height);
        brightBGTexture.SetPixels32(camPixels, 0);
        brightBGTexture.Apply();
        byte[] pngBytes = brightBGTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../camImage.png", pngBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `shader` you are using in `Unity` to display the `Texture2D` from the camera feed?

Comment: My objective is not to display the camera feed but to use the image pixel data directly without displaying the image. I only displayed the camera feed for testing and I did not specify a shader at that point. I used a RawImage on the Canvas and this code to display the camera feed on it `public RawImage camImage;` `camImage.texture = webcamTexture;` I do not think it's a shader issue as the black pixels appear already in the pixel data returned by `GetPixels32()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `SetPixels32`, you **must** call [`Texture2D.Apply`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) to apply the changes to the `Texture2D`.

You should that before encoding the `Texture2D` to png.

```
//save webcam image as png
Texture2D brightBGTexture = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height);
brightBGTexture.SetPixels32(camPixels, 0);
brightBGTexture.Apply();
byte[] pngBytes = brightBGTexture.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../camImage.png", pngBytes);
```

**EDIT**:

Even with calling `Texture2D.Apply()` the problem is still there. This is a bug with the `WebCamTexture` API and you should file for a bug report through the Editor.

Comment: Calling Apply() does not help here. Apply uploads the changed pixels to the graphics card and is not necessary when encoding to png. I have confirmed this by trying your suggestion. Also, as I mentioned before, even when looking directly (before any encoding is done) at the pixel data returned by GetPixels32() the black line exists. By looking I mean printing the pixel data to the console or equivalent.

Comment: *"is not necessary when encoding to png"* Nope. It is necessary. Yes, it is true that it uploads the changes to the graphics cards, it also applies the changes on the Texture2D so that the new pixels will be updated. By calling, Apply you can now access the pixels on the CPU which includes calling the `EncodeToPNG` function. See the linked doc for more information.

Comment: Also, which image is dark? The saved png one?

Comment: OK, I understand, `Apply()` applies the changes to both the GPU and the CPU (I wasn't aware of this).
It is not the whole image that's dark, only the bottom line (1 pixel high line). This black line appears not only in the saved png but also directly in the Color32 array returned from the WebCamTexture by `GetPixels32()`, the elements in this array that represent the bottom line of the image all have the values RGBA = (0,0,0,255).

Comment: ok. is this happening in the Editor or build? Can you try this in a build to see what happens?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I hadn't thought of trying to see what would happen in a build but only in the editor. I did now though and unfortunately the exact same problem remains even when running from a build.

Comment: One last question before I modify my answer: Are you sure that's the code you are using? If not, can you post the exact code you are using for the camera? The code you use to display it on the screen. I want to make sure I am not missing anything before editing my answer.

Comment: Also, it would be good to add screenshot of the what the bad image looks like to your question.

Comment: Yes, that's the code I've been using for testing this issue. After comments I have added a line with `Apply()` but the result has been the same. When the problem first arose I created a new project with only the code relevant to this problem. I've updated my original question with `Apply()` and added the code (the two `for` loops) I used to see the result of `GetPixels32()` in the console. I wont need to display the image on screen so I didn't include code for that when testing. I have added a link to a png image created by the code.

Comment: Yes, I realise now that it was not easy to see the black line on a dark background. I've uploaded an image of the image with a black line as seen on a light background (in this case in MS Paint). The image size is 320 x 240 and it is the line at the absolute bottom of the image that is completely black.

Comment: I can now see the line in the picture. I finally did a test on this but wasn't able to replicate this issue on my side. Check [this](https://codeshare.io/5zERY7) link I just made for **3** possible ways you can fix this. Let me know if any of them works for you.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I've tried the 3 possible fixes you linked to (one by one and together) but the problem remains. Seeing that you were not able to replicate the issue on your side makes me think that the problem might be outside of Unity. As mentioned initially though I do get a correct image when capturing a webcam image in a Processing sketch (on the same computer).

Comment: If the problem is outside of Unity it is not important for me to pinpoint it (except for curing my curiosity) as I would want my code to deal with the possibility of this problem. This as I assume if it happens with my setup it might happen with other potential users setup and hence have to be dealt with.

Comment: Open in Photoshop to verify. If the buttom of the image is still dark then that's unity's WebCamTexture API problem since you have verify that the camera is fine when tested with other apps.

Comment: I have now verified that the bottom of the image is dark in Photoshop as well. I have also reconfirmed that the elements that represent the bottom line of the image all have the values RGBA = (0,0,0,255) in the `Color32` array returned from the `WebCamTexture` by `GetPixels32()`.

Comment: It's a bug. File for a bug report from Unity Editor and also put the defective image in the Project.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you very much for your help. If you want to make your previous comment an answer I will mark the question as answered.